# How to get text form Clipboard with JavaScript in Firefox 56?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a Web Extension for myself which at some point needs to take a text from the Clipboard and process it. I am using Firefox 56 and do not want to update it yet.

Apparently, there is a bug in this version of Firefox, such that **document.execCommand("paste")** does not work even when a permission **"clipboardRead"** is set in the **manifest.json** file.

Are there any other options or workarounds to get the text from the Clipboard?

Comment: is there anything in about:config that would change it? I have no idea if this still works: `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` but it's worth a shot searching for "clipboard"

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I found a workaround. It turned out that the bug has some weird specificity: document.execCommand("paste") does not work in a <textarea>, but it works inside a <div> with contentEditable = "true". Who could have guessed?